# Derivative of absolute value square $|X|^2$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

For the function;

$$Q(X,\gamma)=- \sum_{i,j} \frac{1}{2\gamma}|x_{i,j}|^2+\frac{\gamma}{2}$$

How to calculate derivative $\frac{\delta Q(X,\gamma)}{\delta X} = 0$, as X is in $|x_{i,j}|^2$ form? The expected outcome seems to be $x_{i,j} = 2\gamma$.

Comment: Do you meant to type $|X_{i,j}|^2$?

Comment: The expected outcome is $X=2\gamma$? But you want $\frac{\partial Q(X,\gamma)}{\partial X}$ not $X$...

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Yes, so sorry. I corrected my question.

Comment: @JimmyR. Sorry I updated my question. It is $\frac{\delta Q(X,\gamma)}{\delta X} = 0$

Comment: I don't know what "$X$ is in $|x_{i,j}|$ form" means. Also, taking the standard matrix derivative, I get $\partial Q/\partial X = -X/\gamma $. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @user3658307 I mean on the right hand side of the function, $X$ is written in each element $|x_{i,j}|^2$ form (not whole matrix $X$). I would like to ask  how to solve $\frac{\delta Q(X,\gamma)}{\delta X} = 0$. Is $X/\gamma$ the answer? May you please show the steps how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with how to take differentiate a scalar with respect to a matrix?
If not, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix). All you do is take the element by element derivative. So in this case:
\begin{align} \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x_{\ell k}} 
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\ell k}}\sum_{i,j} \frac{-1}{2\gamma}|x_{ij}|^2 + \frac{\gamma}{2}\\ 
&= \sum_{i,j}\frac{-1}{2\gamma}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\ell k}}|x_{ij}|^2 \\
&=\sum_{i,j}\frac{-1}{2\gamma}\delta_{i\ell}\delta_{jk}2|x_{ij}|\\
&= \frac{|x_{\ell k}|}{\gamma}\\
\therefore \frac{\partial Q}{\partial X} &= \frac{-1}{\gamma}|X| \end{align}
However, this means that $ {\partial Q}/{\partial X} = 0 $ only when $|X|=0$, i.e. $x_{ij}=0\;\forall\;i,j$.

This is intuitively sensible, since clearly $Q$ is minimal when $X$ vanishes, and it is impossible to shrink it further.

Separately, note that if you solve $\partial Q/\partial \gamma=0$, you get: $$ \gamma=\sqrt{\sum_{i,j} |x_{ij}|^2} = || X||_F $$
So that, if plugged into $Q$, we get: $$ Q(X,||X||_F)=\sum_{i,j} \frac{-1}{2||X||_F}|x_{ij}|^2 + \frac{||X||_F}{2}=\frac{-1}{2||X||_F}||X||_F^2 + \frac{||X||_F}{2}=0 $$

Comment: May you tell me the meaning of $\delta$ in the third line $$=\sum_{i,j}\frac{-1}{2\gamma}\delta_{i\ell}\delta_{jk}2|x_{ij}|\\$$?

Comment: @Jan It's the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta): $$ \delta_{ab}=\begin{cases} 1 &\text{ if }a=b\\ 0 &\text{ if }a\ne b\\ \end{cases} $$

Comment: I checked wiki but still don't understand much what are the Kronecker delta doing here? Why the $x$ is $x_{lk}$? and my $j$ and $k$ are not equal, so it is going to be zero?

Comment: @Jan I'm assuming all the matrix entries of $X$ are independent. So then $$ \frac{\partial x_{ij}}{\partial x_{k\ell } }$$ equals $1$ if $i=k$ and $j=\ell$, but otherwise it equals 0 (i.e. if $x_{k\ell}\ne x_{ij}$). Thus, it can be rewritten as $\delta_{i k}\delta_{j\ell}$, for example.